# Deleting the leaf node in a binary tree

Tags: python, data-structures

I am implementing a BST and everything works, even the deletion with two children.The only bug is in the deletion of a leaf which seems such a trivial task.
There seem to be still a reference to the leaf node but I can’t get on top of this issue.Putting node = None doesn’t remove the entire Node.I have also tried del node
without any luck.If you could spot the problem it would be nice.

```
import random


class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.parent = None
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None
        self.level = None

class Tree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0
        self.height = 0

    def _insertion(self, root, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if root.data < data:
            if root.right:
                return self._insertion(root.right, data)
            root.right = new_node
            root.right.parent = root
            root.right_child = root.right
            return
        if root.data > data:
            if root.left:
                return self._insertion(root.left, data)
            root.left = new_node
            root.left.parent = root
            root.left_child = root.left
            return

    def insertion(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if not self.root:
            self.root = new_node
            return
        return self._insertion(self.root, data)

    def _get_height(self, root):
        if not root:
            return -1
        left_height = self._get_height(root.left)
        right_height = self._get_height(root.right)
        return 1 + max(left_height, right_height)

    def get_height(self):
        if not self.root:
            return 0
        return self._get_height(self.root)

    def fill_random(self, num_nodes):
        for i in range(num_nodes):
            random_num = int(random.random()*100)
            self.insertion(random_num)

    def _inorder(self, root):
        if root:
            self._inorder(root.left)
            print(root.data)
            self._inorder(root.right)

    def inorder(self):
        root = self.root
        return self._inorder(root)

    def get_max(self, node):
        while node.right:
            node = node.right
        return node.data

    def search(self, data):
        root = self.root
        while root.right or root.left:
            if root.data < data:
                root = root.right
            if root.data > data:
                root = root.right
            if root.data == data:
                return root
        return None

    def _delete_node(self, root, data):
        if root:
            if root.data < data:
                return self._delete_node(root.right, data)
            if root.data > data:
                return self._delete_node(root.left, data)
            if root.data == data:
                if not root.left and not root.right:
                    root = None
                    return
                if not root.left and root.right:
                    root = root.right
                    root.right = None
                    return
                if not root.right and root.left:
                    root = root.left
                    root.left = None
                    return
                if root.right and root.left:
                    value = self.get_max(root)
                    print(f"This is the value: {value}")
                    root.data = value
                    self._delete_node(root.right, value)

    def delete_node(self, data):
        if not self.root:
            return None
        return self._delete_node(self.root, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_tree = Tree()
    my_tree.insertion(33)
    my_tree.insertion(36)
    my_tree.insertion(25)
    my_tree.insertion(20)
    my_tree.insertion(27)
    my_tree.insertion(35)
    my_tree.insertion(39)
    my_tree.delete_node(33)
    my_tree.inorder()
    my_tree.search(35)
```

Comment: Edit the question to explain: How do you notice the problem? What happens, what should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_delete_node` function, it doesn't help to set `root` to `None`. That only affects the *variable*, but does not bring any change to the tree.

A common "trick" is to return `root` to the caller -- who is then responsible to assign that returned value back to where it is referenced in the tree. For instance, if the recursive call was made with `root.left` as argument, and the recursive call wants to delete that node, it will return `None`, and the caller must then assign (whatever it gets back) to `root.left`. So now the tree *is* mutated as intended.

Here are your `delete_node` functions adapted along that principle:

```
    def _delete_node(self, root, data):
        if root:
            if root.data < data:
                root.right = self._delete_node(root.right, data)
            elif root.data > data:
                root.left = self._delete_node(root.left, data)
            elif not root.left:
                return root.right
            elif not root.right:
                return root.left
            else:
                value = self.get_max(root)
                print(f"This is the value: {value}")
                root.data = value
                root.right = self._delete_node(root.right, value)
        return root

    def delete_node(self, data):
        if self.root:
            self.root = self._delete_node(self.root, data)
```

### Another remark

Your `search` function has some issues:

- The `while` condition should check whether `root` is `None` before accessing any of its attributes.
- The `if` blocks should be tied together with `elif`, otherwise the execution may fall into a second `if` block which is not the intension.

Here is the corrected version:

```
    def search(self, data):
        root = self.root
        while root:
            if root.data < data:
                root = root.right
            elif root.data > data:
                root = root.left
            else:
                return root
        return None
```

### Little improvement

To help debug this code, I altered the `inorder` method with a little change, so that the tree is printed with indentations:

```
    def _inorder(self, root, indent=""):
        if root:
            self._inorder(root.left, indent+"  ")
            print(indent + str(root.data))
            self._inorder(root.right, indent+"  ")
```

This helps to quickly see the structure of the tree. You might even want to switch left and right, so that it looks like a rotated tree.

Comment: really nice answer

Comment: just one question: in the else statement of the deletion function, how can you set root.right to the deletion function.Let’s say that we remove the root.We then find the max, we copy the val of the max to the root.We then call the delete function which is going to return None as this is a leaf node(has no right or left).How can we set self.root.right = None

Comment: That's exactly what will happen at the node that is the parent of that leaf node. At that parent node we make the recursive call, which will return `None`, and so this caller will assign that return value (`None`) to `root.right` ("root" is here that parent node of the leaf).

Comment: Sorry, but I can’t figure how from the root node we can recursively jump to the parent of the leaf node set the right equal to None and then set the parent of the leaf as the right of the root.I am probably dumb but i still don’t get it ;)

Comment: cause the root in this case is the root node, and the right child of the root node is not the parent of the leaf.It works but I don’t get how

Comment: When the *direct* child of the `root` variable is the one that gets deleted, then the one making the recursive call will get back `None`, and will assign this to `root.left` or `root.right` -- which ever the case. Then `root` is returned to the caller. For that caller nothing changes... they assign this node reference back into their `left` or `right`, but that doesn't really change that reference... it is the same as they passed. Perform some step by step debugging to monitor.

Comment: I am actually stupid because I was always skipping the last return root statement.If I am not mistaken when we remove the duplicate we set the right or left child of the parent (root) to None, but then we are goint to return the actual root which is going to be set to root.right. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes, now I finally got it, I needed to draw the whole tree and write down each recursive step and to see what each step returned.Thank you very much trincot, have a nice day and rest of life :)

Answer (score 0):

This block of code doesn't do anything:

```
            if root.data == data:
                if not root.left and not root.right:
                    root = None
                    return
```

because `root` is a local variable; reassigning it to `None` doesn't affect the tree.

What you need to do is change the *parent* node's `right` or `left` pointer.  I'd suggest doing this before you recurse, but you could also solve it by passing the parent node into this function.

Comment: Sam could you have a look at trincot’s solution.I understand everything but I don’t get the root.right = self._delete_node(root.right, value)

Comment: By doing so I am gonna get to the node I want to delete

Comment: But why do I set it to root.right.This way once the deletenode returns None then root.right is going to be set to None.What am I missing?Sorry for asking you but I can’t understand why this thing works.